# Connect Identity server V3 with Sharepoint 2016 - Single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver3

We have identity server V3 used inside my web application. We would like to use same identities to communicate with sharepoint 2016. Any repository or doc available on how to implement single sign on for sharepoint 2016 and Identity server V3 ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to research how to get sharepoint to use IdentityServer as its identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

I prototyped SSO in a test SharePoint 2010 environment a few years and used the links below for assistance. Some of the information may be outdated but I think the relationship between the STS (which in this case would be Identity Server V3 - Thinktecture) and SharePoint has not changed.

I am currently setting up SSO with our SharePoint application as well as other applications. I am using Azure Access Control Service (ACS) to act as a repository for all of the Identity Providers we would like to use. The providers are Facebook,Google,Windows Live ID and LinkedIn. ACS allows you to add custom Identity Providers as well. We have a CRM application that we currently authenticate against within our SharePoint application using claims and forms based authentication. This will be a custom identity provider defined in ACS. I am beginning to work with Thinktecture to be the identity provider that will sit on top of our CRM application. Users will then be able to login to SharePoint with any of the identity providers specified in ACS. We will see how it goes but I believe this will work. I would start with the **General HowTos to using STS in SharePoint** link.

**FederationMetaData.xml editing**

http://stsmetadataeditor.codeplex.com/documentation
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/Geneva/thread/c0791595-2e0d-48cb-82f0-8e0f0bc1809a
http://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/windows-identity-foundationupdating-an-expired-issuer-certificate/

**Regarding the "The issuer of the token is not a trusted issuer" error message.
search string - sharepoint 2010 The issuer of the token is not a trusted issuer**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/sharepoint2010general/thread/f7dbbf1b-f616-4b24-ae0c-e8c76aa300d5

**FedUtil.exe Information**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517284.aspx

**General HowTos to using STS in SharePoint**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955607.aspx